# Android music player - One PlayerActivity at a time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-music-player

I'm programming a music player and I have 2 activities:

1. The first one (MainActivity) contains a ListView of songs, and I set an OnItemClickListener (inside its onCreate() method) which opens a new activity called PlayerActivity passing the position of the item that has been tapped:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       Intent intent;
       ArrayList<String> artistsTitles;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerActivity.class);
           artistsTitles=getArtistTitle();
           ListView mainList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainList);
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, artistsTitles);
           mainList.setAdapter(adapter);
           mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   intent.putExtra("currentSong", position);
                   startActivity(intent);
               }
           });
       }

       private ArrayList<String> getArtistTitle() {
           ContentResolver musicResolve = getContentResolver();
           String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
           String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE};
           Uri uri=android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
           Cursor cursor = musicResolve.query(uri, projection, selection, null, null);

           ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
           while(cursor.moveToNext())
               arrayList.add(cursor.getString(0)+" - "+cursor.getString(1));

           return arrayList;
       }
   }
   ```
2. The second one (PlayerActivity) has an ArrayList of the string paths of the songs, and with a MediaPlayer, plays the song having the item position and accessing to the ArrayList with it:

   ```
   public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       ArrayList<String> songs;
       MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
           songs=new ArrayList<String>();
           songs=getSongs();
           String songPath=songs.get(intent.getIntExtra("songID", 0));
           mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(songPath));
           try {
               mediaPlayer.reset();
               mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(songPath));
               mediaPlayer.prepare();
               mediaPlayer.start();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       private ArrayList<String> getSongs() {
           ContentResolver musicResolve = getContentResolver();

           String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
           String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
           Uri uri=android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
           Cursor cursor = musicResolve.query(uri, projection, selection, null, null);

           ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
           while(cursor.moveToNext())
               s.add(cursor.getString(0));

           return s;
       }
   }
   ```

It works perfectly, but when I back forward to the first activity (MainActivity) and then I tap to another item (or to the same), it creates another one PlayerActivity, so the app is playing 2 songs at the same time.

How can I implement it so that it only creates one PlayerActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Check the launchMode of the Activity in your Manifest.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: I've checked for singleTask and singleInstance, but it does the same...

Comment: than we need more code of your activity. Where is your mediaplayer initialized, where is your song loading placed,...

Comment: Code uploaded! Thanks for your attention.

Comment: if you start an activity via Intend onCreate() is called. In your onCreate function you are creating always a new mediaplayer, also if it is already exists. a simple nullcheck `if(mediaPlayer==null)` should do the trick. I would recommand to explizit stop the current playing media. Take a look at the state diagram at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: The nullcheck does not work too... It seems it creates a new PlayerActivity once you tap on an item, regardless of wheter or not it existed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I tried to pass via Intent a MediaPlayer instance created in MainActivity, but it seems it cannot be done. So, here's my solution:

1. Create a class that extends Application and instantiate MediaPlayer there, so that I have a global MediaPlayer object:

   ```
   import android.app.Application;
   import android.media.MediaPlayer;

   public class MyApp extends Application {
       MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=null;

       public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
           return mediaPlayer;
       }

       public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
           this.mediaPlayer=mediaPlayer;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Set MyApp as the name of my application in the AndroidManifest.xml:

   ```
   <application
   android:name="NicoPlayer"
   ...>
       ...
   </application>
   ```
3. Create a MediaPlayer instance in PlayerActivity and assign the global MediaPlayer instance to it calling getMediaPlayer(), all in onCreate() method. Once this is done and mediaPlayer is playing, assign it to the global MediaPlayer instance calling setMediaPlayer():

   ```
   mediaPlayer=((NicoPlayer)this.getApplication()).getMediaPlayer();
   if(mediaPlayer==null)
       mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(songPath));
   ((NicoPlayer)this.getApplication()).setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
   try {
       mediaPlayer.reset();
       mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(songPath));
       mediaPlayer.prepare();
       mediaPlayer.start();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```